# What does "vat capacity upgrade" do?

Tags: sunset-overdrive

I finished a mission that increased vat capacity but I have no idea what it did. What does it mean and what benefits does it bestow?

Answer (score 1):

The First Vat mission gives 20 Overcharge as its "Health". On my second Vat mission, which is after I did the Capacity quest, I had 35 Overcharge, so it just makes the Vats, tankier, I assume. Heh. Pun.